# PreCalculus Composition of Functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

If $h(x) = ((x - 2)^2)$, find $h(x + 1)$,

$$=((x+1)-2)^2
=(x-1)(x-1)
=x^2-2x+1$$.

I'm certain I've made a mistake in here

Comment: Why do you think you have made a mistake?

Comment: I'm terrible with these problems. Did I do it correctly?

Comment: Yes it is perfectly right! You did the substitution well.

Comment: Everything here looks correct @Joe.

Comment: @Joe, just a tip - you can always check by plugging in some values for $x$, for example $x=2$: $h(3)=1=h(2+1)=2^2-2\cdot2+1$.

Answer (score 2):

Your work is correct. If you are confused by the swarm of symbols, I find it is sometimes helpful when learning this sort of thing to actually write a box in place of the variable in the function. That's the role of the variable argument, anyway--a placeholder. Then you can fill in the box with whatever you want. With enough practice, you can do this mentally and keep it straight without having to really write a box.

For example, you can write your function as
$$h(\square) = (\square - 2)^2$$
so you can plug "stuff" into the box without worrying about the name of the variable.  Some examples:
$$h(\boxed{x+1}) = (\boxed{x+1}-2)^2 = (x-1)^2 = 2^2-2x+1$$
$$h(\boxed{-x}) = (\boxed{-x}-2)^2=x^2+4x+4$$
$$h(\boxed{x^2+2}) = (\boxed{x^2+2}-2)^2 = x^4$$
and even
$$h(\boxed{h(x)}) = (\boxed{(x-2)^2}-2)^2 = (x^2-4x+2)^2=x^4-8x^3+20x^2-16x+4$$